# Generic with union type throwing not assignable error

Tags: typescript, generics, redux

I have a reducer that has an action creator that can be an array of two different types of object, each has their own interface. However, I am getting this error

```
Type '(A | B)[]' is not assignable to type 'B[]'.
  Type 'A | B' is not assignable to type 'B'.
    Property 'productionId' is missing in type 'A' but required in type 'B'
```

I suspect this error is due to both interface having similar values, except B has one extra value than A?

Here is the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20id%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20B%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20id%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20productionId%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20IAction%3CData%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20type%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20data%3A%20Data%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ISelectionOptionsReducerState%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20a%3A%20A%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20b%3A%20B%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20initialState%3A%20ISelectionOptionsReducerState%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20a%3A%20%5B%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20b%3A%20%5B%5D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20TAction%20%3D%20IAction%3CArray%3CA%20%7C%20B%3E%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20TReducer%20%3D%20(%0D%0A%20%20state%3A%20ISelectionOptionsReducerState%2C%0D%0A%20%20action%3A%20TAction%0D%0A)%20%3D%3E%20ISelectionOptionsReducerState%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20selectionOptionsReducer%3A%20TReducer%20%3D%20(%0D%0A%20%20state%3A%20ISelectionOptionsReducerState%20%3D%20initialState%2C%0D%0A%20%20action%3A%20TAction%0D%0A)%3A%20ISelectionOptionsReducerState%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20Object.freeze(state)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20let%20newState%3A%20ISelectionOptionsReducerState%20%3D%20state%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20switch%20(action.type)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20case%20'1'%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20newState.a%20%3D%20action.data%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20break%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20case%20'2'%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20newState.b%20%3D%20action.data%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20break%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20default%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20state%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20return%20newState%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A)

Here is the full reproducible code

```
interface A {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

interface B {
  id: number;
  productionId: number;
  name: string;
}

interface IAction<Data> {
  type: string;
  data: Data;
}

interface ISelectionOptionsReducerState {
  a: A[];
  b: B[];
}

let initialState: ISelectionOptionsReducerState = {
  a: [],
  b: []
};

type TAction = IAction<Array<A | B>>;
type TAction = IAction<A[] | B[]>; <= this didn't work either

type TReducer = (
  state: ISelectionOptionsReducerState,
  action: TAction
) => ISelectionOptionsReducerState;

const selectionOptionsReducer: TReducer = (
  state: ISelectionOptionsReducerState = initialState,
  action: TAction
): ISelectionOptionsReducerState => {
  Object.freeze(state);

  let newState: ISelectionOptionsReducerState = state;

  switch (action.type) {
    case '1':
      newState.a = action.data;
      break;
    case '2':
      newState.b = action.data; <= error happen here
      break;
    default:
      return state;
  }

  return newState;
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Couple things:

First,

```
Array<A | B>
(A | B)[]
```

are all identical.

Second, the reason why `A` is assignable to both is because all properties of A are also in B.

Third, don't mutate state. Reassigning it isn't enough.

```
> const x = {}
undefined
> const y = x
undefined
> y.a = 1
1
> x
{ a: 1 }
```

You can splat into a new object: `let newState = { ...state }` - that's generally sufficient.

Ok. You can't assign a value of type `A | B` to something that's type `B`. You've used something else (`type`) to signal a different value, but TS can't know about that unless you tell it. There are a number of different ways you can do it.

First, assert:

```
newState.b = action.data as B[];
```

This is effectively telling TS to bugger off. More often than not, this is fine... If you're doing something really questionable, TS will make you assert to `unknown` first. That's not the case, here, though.

but there are better ways to do it.

Slightly better: type guards

This requires refactoring out the switch:

```
function isA(x: any): x is IAction<Array<A>> {
  return x.type === '1'
}

function isB(x: any): x is IAction<Array<B>> {
  return x.type === '2'
}

...

if (isA(action)) {
  newState.a = action.data;
} else if (isB(action)) {
  newState.b = action.data;
}
```

(**note**: I can't actually get this to work... the code is right, I'm just getting type `never` for action after the first check - not sure what's going on here)

Finally, [let TypeScript do the resolution for you via duck-typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20id%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20B%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20id%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20productionId%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ISelectionOptionsReducerState%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20a%3A%20A%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20b%3A%20B%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20initialState%3A%20ISelectionOptionsReducerState%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20a%3A%20%5B%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20b%3A%20%5B%5D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20IAction%3CT%2C%20D%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20type%3A%20T%0D%0A%20%20data%3A%20D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ActionA%20%3D%20IAction%3C'1'%2C%20Array%3CA%3E%3E%0D%0Atype%20ActionB%20%3D%20IAction%3C'2'%2C%20Array%3CB%3E%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20TAction%20%3D%20ActionA%20%7C%20ActionB%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20TReducer%20%3D%20(%0D%0A%20%20state%3A%20ISelectionOptionsReducerState%2C%0D%0A%20%20action%3A%20TAction%0D%0A)%20%3D%3E%20ISelectionOptionsReducerState%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20selectionOptionsReducer%3A%20TReducer%20%3D%20(%0D%0A%20%20state%3A%20ISelectionOptionsReducerState%20%3D%20initialState%2C%0D%0A%20%20action%3A%20TAction%0D%0A)%3A%20ISelectionOptionsReducerState%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20Object.freeze(state)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20let%20newState%20%3D%20%7B%20...state%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20switch%20(action.type)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20case%20'1'%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20newState.a%20%3D%20action.data%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20break%0D%0A%20%20%20%20case%20'2'%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20newState.b%20%3D%20action.data%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20return%20newState%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A).

The tl;dr of that is that if you have a property within an object that correlates with a type, TS can automatically pick up types if that property is sufficiently unique.

Answer (score 6):

> I suspect this error is due to both interface having similar values,
>   except B has one extra value than A?

Yes, you can assign B to A, but not A to B.

You need type guard:

```
function isA(data: A | B): data is A {
  return typeof (data as B).productionId === 'undefined'
}

function isB(data: A | B): data is B {
  return typeof (data as B).productionId === 'string'
}

... 

case '1':
  newState.a = action.data.filter(isA);
  break;
case '2':
  newState.b = action.data.filter(isB);
  break;
```

Edit:
(I can't write comments)

@Tyler Sebastian

```
Array<A | B>
(A | B)[]
```

are identical, but `A[] | B[]` is diffrent